# Message: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:

Tags: jss

We have `Sitecore 9.1.1 - JSS` instance at my local machine. While opening page in the experience editor we are getting below error message:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:

[1] Ensure that the configured path to the Node.js executable is valid.
    Configured executable path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\
    Make sure the Node executable is available at this path.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance..ctor(String entryPointScript, String projectPath, String[] watchFileExtensions, String commandLineArguments, ILogger nodeOutputLogger, IDictionary`2 environmentVars, Int32 invocationTimeoutMilliseconds, Boolean launchWithDebugging, Int32 debuggingPort, String nodePath)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance..ctor(NodeServicesOptions options, Int32 port)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.NodeServicesOptions.<.ctor>b__3_0()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.GetOrCreateCurrentNodeInstance()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

We have checked the following things:

1. Update the node path in the file `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config`

`<NodePath>C:\Program Files\nodejs\</NodePath>`

1. Given full permission to user everyone on the above mentioned (#1) path.
2. Uninstalled the NodeJs and re-installed the NodeJS. But no luck..
3. Checked blog(https://gary.wenneker.org/sitecore-jss-failed-to-start-node-process/). Since we have just one version of NodeJs installed on our local instance, so NVM has not use for us.

Seeking help here from community ...

Comment: Maybe the NodePath parameter's location path is not correct, Did you verify nodejs is installed in that path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node path should include node.exe as well. So it's value should be:

`<NodePath>C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe</NodePath>`

Answer (score 4):

The following steps helped me to resolve the same issue:

1. Added `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` to **PATH** environment variable (for User)

[image]

2. Added **full permissions** for the App Pool user (in my case default **IIS_IUSRS**) for this folder - `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

[image]

3. **Bounced IIS**